# Twitter Location undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, location

I am trying to plot tweets to a Google Map but the location is always undefined, everything else works fine and if I use an actual location string, again, fine. I have checked the JSON and location is specified.

Dose anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

My code..

```
function loadTweets(){
        var url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed&callback=?';
        var tweets = $('#twitter');
        $.getJSON(url,
            function(data){
              $.each(data.results, function(i,item){ 
                    // parse image url
                    var imgString = parseImg(item.profile_image_url, item.from_user);

                    var urlString = parseUrl(item.from_user, item.id);

                    var tweetString = parseTweet(item.text);

                    //tweets.append('<div>'+imgString+'<p>'+urlString+'</p>'+'<p>'+tweetString+'</p></div>');

                    var contentString = '<div>'+imgString+'<p>'+urlString+'</p>'+'<p>'+tweetString+'</p></div>';

                    console.log(item.location);

              });
            });
    };
```

Returned JSON sample

```
from_user: "Elvira_Sysyn",
from_user_id: 539551608,
from_user_id_str: "539551608",
from_user_name: "Elvira Sysyn",
geo: null,
location: "San Francisco, CA",
id: 258898154894786560,
id_str: "258898154894786560",
iso_language_code: "en",
metadata: {
result_type: "recent"
},
profile_image_url: "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2519826073/kl_normal.jpg",
profile_image_url_https: "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2519826073/kl_normal.jpg",
source: "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;",
text: "woww!! the big surprise, just 1 days your followers can reach 3000 up,  visit ---&gt; http://t.co/UqhRKnKr",
to_user: null,
to_user_id: 0,
to_user_id_str: "0",
to_user_name: null
```

I really have to get this finished, I'd appreciate any help..

Comment: is data object from getJson having locaton just console data object and see

Answer (score 0):

I put your exact code in a fiddle and location does not exist in the JSON  that is getting returned, thus it is undefined.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8DmJ/2/)

Comment: HUH - what about this line.. location: "San Francisco, CA",

Comment: Oh CRAP! I just logged the whole object and it isn't there. Do you know why or how I can fix it!? :'(

Comment: "I have checked the JSON and location is specified" - good enough.